# How to have assigned previous onion address for my hidden service?

Tags: onion-routing

I installed Tor on my Linux CentOS and edited torrc configuration file, setting the hidden service directory (HiddenServiceDir).

After some time it happen that i changed this directory in Tor configuration file torrc and restarted Tor. It appears that my hidden service has new .onion address and old one do not show my webpage. So my question is, please how i can have my previous onion address again?

Answer (score 3):

Basing on [official docs](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-hidden-service.html.en) you should copy-paste content of old HiddenServiceDir to your new HiddenServiceDir location (you should overwrite new ones). There are only two files: `hostname` and  `private_key`.

Probably you'll need root privillages to do it.